# How to insert set type into cassandra from a dataframe in spark

Tags: dataframe, cassandra, set

I have a data frame which looks like this -

```
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+
| Address_Type|    Address_Zip|     Address_City|         Name|           ID|
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+
|         HOME|         141101|           Nevada|       George|       SO-123|
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+
|       OFFICE|         123561|               LA|       George|       SO-123|
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+
|         HOME|         141234|         New York|         Jane|       SC-128|
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+
|         BILL|         111009|             UTAH|         Jane|       SC-128|
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I'm trying to save the data in cassandra where there is a field named Address which is of type Set. Now I want to save the address which is the combination of all field associated with address tag. So that the new Dataframe looks like -

```
+-------------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------+
|         Name|           ID|                                             Address|
+-------------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------+
|       George|       SO-123|{"Address_Type: "HOME", "Address_City": "Nevada",...|
+-------------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------+
|         Jane|       SC-128|{"Address_Type: "HOME", "Address_City": "New York",.|
+-------------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

and I can easily save it to the cassandra table.

How can I do this?

Comment: That looks like a UDT not a set?

Comment: RussS : I need to insert into a table where address is a set and inside there will be address_type and address_city. A user can have multiple addresses, hence the field is set<text>.

Comment: ... That sounds like a Set<Address> not Set<Text> since each "address has a addressType and an address city

Comment: Sets do not have attribute names they just have contents, on that note there is an automatic conversion of DF of sets of udts or rows into C* udts. So you would just save into the matching table and it would work

Comment: I'm new to Spark and I'm using 1.6.0 in Java. Can you show me how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that needs to happen is to match up the DataFrame with the Cassandra Table. So if you are inserting into a Cassandra table with type Set. You just need a dataframe whose schema contains a column of that name of type Array where the internal structure of those rows matches the `Address` type.

So in your case the dataframe should look like

`| Name | ID | Addresses Array<Address> |`

Which would match a cassandra table

`| Name String, ID String, Addresses Set<Addresses>|`

With that matching the command would be

`df.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(...).save()`